# In Angular 4 how do i lose focus on keyup

Tags: angular

I created a plunkr to explain what im talking about
https://plnkr.co/edit/42Gcd8jayIO3EReiKCLf?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input (keyup.enter)=func() >
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
  }
  func(){
    console.log("lose focus here")
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I want to lose focus on input box on keyup

Answer (score 2):

You can lose focus by setting **`$event.target.blur()`** on keypress event,

```
<input (keyup.enter)="$event.target.blur()" >
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/mYN2GnAvy0JTjVgRnvwt?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of achieving what you want, another example is to use @ViewChild and ElementRef.

Html:

```
<input #myEventRef (keyup.enter)="myEvent()" />
```

Component:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";


@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private readonly el: ElementRef) {
    }

    @ViewChild("myEventRef") myEventRef: ElementRef;

    myEvent() {
        this.myEventRef.nativeElement.blur();
    }
}
```

And you can go further using @HostListener, which i am not going to display.